# Create category post shortcode

Tags: categories, shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode for my theme without using plugins. I tried this `http://wpgeneratetool.com/short-code/` but i can not figure out how to create.

I want to create something like the following where I can set category name and post per page.

Example like `[categorypost cat="pant"  post-per-page="5" ]`

HTML output will be title, post thumbnail and permalink.

Example bellow

```
<div><h1>post title</h1><a herf="permalink url"> post thumbnail</a></div>
```

I've tried with `http://wpgeneratetool.com/short-code/`

```
function cat-post($atts){
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(  

        '$category-name' => '$atts['id']',
        '$post-title' => 'get_the_title($post_id)',
        '$post-link' => 'get_the_permalink($post_id)',
        '$post-image' => 'get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id,  'thumbnail')',
        $post-data ='<div><a href="'.$link.'">'.$image.'<h5>'.$title.'</h5></a></div>';
    return $data;

        ), $atts ) )

}
add_shortcode( 'categorypost', 'cat-post' );
```

but I know this code is not correct.

Comment: You can't use `-` in a function name like `cat-post`. That's illegal. You could do `cat_post` thought.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but rest of think ok ?

Comment: No! it isn't correct, there are lot syntax error. Read these examples https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Never ever use `extract()`. It was removed from core more than two years ago for very specific reasons. The use of `extract()` is even highly discouraged in normal PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needs a complete rewrite...

```
add_shortcode( 'categorypost', 'cat_post' );

function cat_post( $atts ) {

    // attributes for shortcode
   if ( isset( $atts['cat'] ) ) {$cats = $atts['cat'];} else {return;}
   if ( isset( $atts['posts_per_page'] ) ) {$posts_per_page = $atts['posts_per_page'];} else {$posts_per_page = -1;}

   // get the category posts
   $category = get_category_by_slug( $cats );
   if ( !is_object( $category ) ) {return;}
   $args = array(
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page
   );
   $posts = get_posts( $args );

   // create the list output
   if ( count( $posts ) > 0 ) {
       foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
           $link = get_permalink( $post->ID );
           $title = $post->post_title;
           $image = get_post_thumbnail( $post->ID,'thumbnail' );
           $output .= '<div id="postrow-'.$post->ID.'" class="postrow">';
           $output .= '<a class="postlink" href="'.$link.'">' . $image;
           $output .= '<h5 class="posttitle">' . $title . '</h5></a></div>';
       }
   }
   return $output;
}
```

Example shortcode usage: `[categorypost cat="pant" posts_per_page="5"]`

Comment: Thank you so much for kind help. i think it will work if we can tweak a bit. i tried but it show first time error. then add `}` after ` return $output; }` then in dreamweaver error not showing but one page show error line number 216 which is ` $image = get_post_thumbnail($post->ID);`. after then then add `}` after ` $atts ) );` error not showing but data not coming

Comment: finally i did. `$image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail');` when i put it then it is work. thanks man. thank a lot.  one more thing is possible also shorting option. like assdining designing

Comment: Take this as a downvote, never ever use `extract()`. It was removed from core more than two years ago for very specific reasons. The use of `extract()` is even highly discouraged in normal PHP. Usage of `extract()` was also removed from the codex, so you are definitely doing it wrong

Comment: @PieterGoosen this is working but i don't about extract issue. would you please tell us which we can code then without using `extract()`. i am not expert on WordPress yet

Comment: okay I removed `extract` and added some classes/IDs for styling via CSS.

Comment: @majick. thank you so much. is there anyway to in shortcode add  assdining designing options

Comment: @majick . is there any way to contact with you in future for some projects

Comment: just create a new question? the whole point of this site is not to rely on one person's expertise... i guess you could paste the link to it here and i'll get notified, but super busy with multiple projects and really cannot guarantee i'll be available.

Comment: Is the code is correct because I am getting syntax error, unexpected end of file. at the end one } is missing

Comment: @NarenVerma yes you are correct, it was missing close } for the count condition check, looking at the top I see the questioner had the same problem but I wasn't clear on what was meant. fixed.